# OCaml custom compiler warnings

Tags: ocaml, compiler-warnings

Is it possible to make `ocamlc` produce custom warnings when compiling? I have some half-finished code, and I want to be reminded that it's not finished. As an example: I want to write a `reverse` function. I can't be bothered to work out how to code it up at the moment, so I just write something that type-checks.

```
let reverse xs = xs
```

I would like to write something like

```
let reverse xs = Compiler_Warning "TODO: reverse"; xs
```

Is that possible? I'd be interested to hear any tricks for achieving a similar result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common trick is to raise an exception with a `failwith "not implemented"` or just `assert false`.

This will give you a warning if you have unused parameters in the unimplemented function. Although, they are disable by default. So you need to add -Wall option, to enable them.

Also, you can just add an intentionally unused variable in your implementation, like:

```
let reverse xs =
  let unimplemented = () in 
  xs
```

Comment: Thanks ivg. The `failwith` and `assert false` tricks aren't appropriate in my case because I want the warning raised at compile-time. But I like very much your `let unimplemented = ()` trick, so I'll accept your answer on that basis.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested by the [cppo pre-processor](http://mjambon.com/cppo-manual-0.9.2.txt) that describes itself as a `cpp` equivalent for OCaml programs and features a `#warning` directive. It seems to be available through `opam`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with extension points, and currently the plan is to [annotate deprecated functions](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5854) in a similar fashion. As ivg has mentioned, `failwith "TODO"` is standard for what you want, but you will not get compile time warnings --though you may get unused argument warnings for each argument in the function.